# Different values in a JAVA code

Tags: java

I have this code where I should get a value from it:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        float a=4, b=8 ;
        int i=2, j=16 ;
        double sol1, sol2, sol3, sol4;
        sol1=(a+2*b/j);
        sol2=(a/(b-4)+i);
        sol3=-(b-i/j);
        sol4=(i*a+j/b);
        System.out.println(sol1);
        System.out.println(sol2);
        System.out.println(sol3);
        System.out.println(sol4);
    }
}
```

[And here is a Java fiddle of the solution](http://ideone.com/hiNoYQ):

```
5
3
-8
10
```

But in sol3, my calculated value is not -8, it is -7.875, so why it takes it as -8.0.

I tried to decompose the sol3 alone into separate execution [like in this fiddle](http://ideone.com/hAa7hj):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        float a=4, b=8 ;
        int i=2, j=16 ;
        double sol1, sol2, sol3, sol4;

        sol1=-i/j;
        sol2=b+sol1;
        sol3 = -sol2;
        System.out.println(sol1);
        System.out.println(sol2);
        System.out.println(sol3);

    }
}
```

And still giving me -8.0 and on a calculator it is -7.875. I know is too easy but I can't figure it out why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sol1=-i/j;
```

is evaluated to 0 since i < j and both of them are `int`. Change one of them to float or double in order to perform floating point division.

Comment: Also the samething for `sol3=-(b-i/j);`

Comment: @Kilanny Yes, changing `i` or `j` to float or double will take care of that too.

Comment: Sir, why 0.5%28 is equal to 0.5 ?

Comment: @androidnation `0.5%28` is not equal to 28.

Comment: Sorry it is equal to 0.5. Why all modulos that starts with number less than one is equal to this number

Comment: @androidnation For the same reason that 1%28 is 1 and 5%28 is 5.

Answer (score 1):

Variables `i` and `j` are `int`s.  The expression `i/j` is evaluted using integers, so the result of `2/16` is zero.  Try

```
sol1 = -((double)i) / j;
```

Comment: Sir, why 0.5%28 is equal to 0.5 ?

Comment: Because one value (0.5) is already a float, to the `int` is converted to `float` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
sol3=-(b-i/j);
```

You have to explicitly cast the solution to double or float. Because both i and j are of type int, So you have to write as

```
sol3=-(b-(double)(i/j));
```

Comment: Sir, why 0.5%28 is equal to 0.5 ?

Comment: 0.5%28 is equal to 0.5 in case it is double and 0 in case it is int not 28. Can you explain the scenario. Also, It is not Sir.